# Recursive Clojure function not recurring when called from last place in the calling function

Tags: recursion, clojure

This is my caller

```
(resolveEntity [r entity-id]
  (println "resolve" entity-id)
  (recursive-get r entity-id)
  (cache entity-id)
)
```

Called function is

```
(defn recursive-get [r entity-id]
(println "recursive" entity-id)
  (let [e (f (merge {} (-> r :conns first d/db (d/entity entity-id))))]
    (alter-var-root #'cache assoc entity-id e)
    (for [[k v] e]
      (if (:db/isComponent (k components))
        (if (not= (class v) Long)
          (map #(recursive-get r %) v)
          (recursive-get r v)
      )))))
```

The called function is called just once. If I remove the last line in the caller (cache entity-id), then it recurs every time that I want it to, but I need to return something else  (cache entity-id).

I tested a similar but simpler code (a recursive function not called at the tail of a calling function) the REPL and it worked, so I am left crashing my head against the table.

Comment: Are you sure you want map (your recursive function) over v? map is lazy, so it doesn't need to execute right away. You could wrap it in a  (doall).

Comment: Thank you guys, did not see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been bitten by a Lazy-Bug!

If you remove the last line then the return value of the function is the result of `(recursive-get r entity-id)` which the repl then iterates through so it can print it. The act of printing each value causes each entry in the lazy collection to be evaluated. When you put another line after that, the result of the `map` is ignored: nothing reads the entries, and they remain in the **unrealized lazy state** forever and the computation never happens.

To fix this wrap it in a call to `dorun`:

```
(dorun (recursive-get r entity-id))
```

Or if you need to save the result then use `doall` instead.